# Not Authorized while running intern test from jenkins to sauce

Tags: intern, saucelabs

I get the below message even after setting the sauce credentials in my grunfile.js and also exposing them as sys variables too..

> grunt intern:sauce ?[4mRunning "intern:sauce" (intern) task?[24m
>   Listening on 0.0.0.0:9000 Starting tunnel... Using no proxy for
>   connecting to Sauce Labs REST API.
>   ?[1m********************************************************?[22m A
>   newer version of Sauce Connect (build 1283) is available! Download it
>   here: https://saucelabs.com/downloads/sc-4.3-linux.tar.gz
>   ?[1m********************************************************?[22m
>   Started scproxy on port 44054. Starting secure remote tunnel VM...
>   Error: Not authorized Error: Not authorized at reject at
>   readStartupMessage at at Array.some at Socket. at
>   Socket.EventEmitter.emit events.js:117:20 at Socket.
>    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit
>   events.js:92:17 at emitReadable <_stream_readable.js:408:10> at
>   emitReadable <_stream_readable.js:404:5>

Answer (score 0):

In your "Execute Shell", set

> export TRAVIS_COMMIT=$BUILD_NUMBER
>
> export SAUCE_USERNAME=...
>
> export SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY=...
>
> node_modules/.bin/intern-runner config=tests/intern_sauce

See screenshot below:

[image: Jenkins config]

This works for me, hope it works for you too!